# How to pull a single Shopify variant field with product list

Tags: php, rest, shopify, response

I am pulling a product list back with Rest API in PHP for Shopify:

```
        $resp = $Rest->get(
            'products',
            [],
            [
                'limit'            => 250,
                'fields'           => 'id,title,variants',
                'published_status' => 'published',
                'status'           => 'active'
            ]
        );
```

This results in the following response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 237462354
            [title] => Product 1 title
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [product_id] => 237462354
                            [id] => 1481824
                            [title] => Default Title
                            [price] => 105.99
                            [sku] => MYSKU11002
                            [position] => 1
                            [inventory_policy] => deny
                            [compare_at_price] => 
                            [fulfillment_service] => manual
                            [inventory_management] => shopify
                            [option1] => Default Title
                            [option2] => 
                            [option3] => 
                            [created_at] => 2022-08-12T10:13:39-04:00
                            [updated_at] => 2022-08-16T14:55:31-04:00
                            [taxable] => 1
                            [barcode] => 814812747124
                            [grams] => 2268
                            [image_id] => 
                            [weight] => 5
                            [weight_unit] => lb
                            [old_inventory_quantity] => 1
                            [requires_shipping] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

What I would prefer is the following response type:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 237462354
            [title] => Product 1 title
            [variants] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [product_id] => 237462354
                            [sku] => MYSKU11002
                        )

                )

        )
```

This basically requires modifying the fields so that we just get the `product_id` and `sku` for the variants returned per product.

I have tried using `fields=id,title,variants.sku`, `fields=id,title,variants/sku`, `fields=id,title,variants[sku]` with no luck.

Is this possible? You can do it in GraphQL - I know that much, so it would make sense if it were possible in the PHP Rest API also.

Comment: It's not possible to specify the single fields of the variant. The only solution is GraphQL

Comment: There is almost no chance the RestAPI will ever be capable of cherry-picking subfields like variant SKU. Shopify has made it clear, adopt GQL or suffer with the existing RestAPI and all its limits.